# How to find username and passwords in SQL table using C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I currently have a table on a sql server named "users" with the following columns/datatypes respectively:

```
username/nvarchar(max)
email/nvarchar(max)
password/nvarchar(max)
```

My table has one row:

```
[test][test@gmail.com][test]
```

I am using the following code to search through the table. I take the username (which is actually the email) and split it so that it becomes test. I then try to select the row that has test as it's username. Once I create the reader, I am trying to compare the email in the table with the username and the password from the table with the password:

```
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
  {
        conn.ConnectionString ="connectionstring";
        conn.Open();
        //grab the username and password from the request
        string username = req.Form[0]; //test@gmail.com
        string password = req.Form[1]; //test

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(username) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            //hash the password
            //lookup the password and username in the table
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT username, email, password FROM users WHERE username = '@{0}'", username.Split('@')[0]), conn);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while(reader.Read())//THIS always evaluates to false
            {
                if (reader[1] == username && reader[2] == password) { return true; }
            } 
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I have debugged it with Visual Studio 2013 so I know for sure that my username and password is test@gmail.com and test. I don't get any exceptions and reader has the three column values in it's object, but it can't find the only row in the table that matches the username. I am very new to SQL queries so it is very possible that I am doing something wrong there. My problem is it never enters the while loop to check the email with the username and the password with the password. Also am I using appropriate datatypes for this?

The debugger shows that reader has the following:

```
 Depth: 0
 FieldCount: 3
 HasRows: false
 IsClosed: false
 RecordsAffected: -1
 VisibleFieldCount: 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a problem with your query syntax:
You are writing it up, as if you are passing a parameter in it, which results in the following:

```
SELECT username, email, password FROM users WHERE username = '@test'
```

What you really want is this string

```
SELECT username, email, password FROM users WHERE username = 'test'
```

To do this you have to change your SQL command to this:

```
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT username, email, password FROM users WHERE username = '{0}'", username.Split('@')[0]), conn);
```

Your problem was the following: Because you were checking against '@test' you weren't getting results back. following this your reader didn't read any data, because there was none and therefore `reader.Read()` never returned true and your while loop failed.

After this you will parameterize your query, because of reasons!

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT username, email, password FROM users WHERE username = @usern", conn);
command.Parameters.Add('usern', username.Split('@')[0]);
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while(reader.Read()) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will be hashing and salting but this is just my first time using sql so I am running some test code. The definitely fixes my loop issue thank you!

Comment: we can only address so many problems at once @J.Steen. But yes, this is valid as well.

Comment: @Serv Which is why I put it as a comment, and not as another answer. =)

Comment: @WarGravy If this is your first time using sql then don't, using SQL in C# only makes sense for legacy imho, learn linq instead and avoid the whole host of issues of Learning SQL, targeting diferent versions of it and get rid of all the injection security issues at the same time. Will learn it faster and end up with a LOT less code

Comment: Understanding SQL is a crucial point of understanding how LINQ works. The latter only translates into the former. You can do so much wrong by not knowing the basics.

Comment: @Ronan Are you suggesting using a NoSQL database integrated into my  web application?

Comment: @WarGravy absolutely not, i'm suggesting you change the way you QUERY the database (using linq to entities and working in a fully type safe, compile time validated language within C#). Not the DB itself, read up on linq to entities,you don't need to switch db engines at all

Comment: @Serv I'll have to strongly disagree here, Learning some abstract topics around SQL (unrelated to the language itself but to the way queries are optimized) can be usefull, to do the parallel Learning sql helps no more in linq than Learning assembler helps in C#, actually i've seen plenty of linq anti patterns applied by people because they wrote it "like SQL". Yes it translates to SQL, but that's all it does, it's not a 1:1 mapping to SQL as it's read and if you use it at the expression level it's meant to be used at it should NOT look like SQL at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You are Quering DataBase Like this

> SELECT username, email, password FROM users

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.connection = con;

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT username, email, password FROM users";
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while(reader.Read())//THIS always evaluates to false
{
     if (reader.GetString(0) == username &&
         reader.GetString(2) == password) 
     {
         return true; 
     }
}
```

**EDIT:**

*Later Understood Your ResultSet Returns only one row*, which is not best practice 
      You have to split it in your code as suggested by @Serv and then Check for
      UserName and Passwords

Comment: Yep same problem, it still skips right past the while loop.

Comment: Yes thank you, I found out that I did have another bug with the if statement and needed to call .ToString().